# Unique Counters For All Items In ListView - Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, listview, google-cloud-firestore, counter

Disclaimer: I saw some solutions on stackoverflow but none of them had listviews generated with data from firestore. So a hint on that questions will not help me :/

Hey
I have a little problem with my counters within my ListView from the Firestore database. As you can see below, I am trying to create unique counters for each entry in the list from the database. The number currently changes with each entry, so it is identical everywhere.

It may be useful to know when you try to help me solving that problem, that in the following I still need the number of the counter in order to save it in the database.
(I saw other solutions where that point was pretty heavy)

So here is the extract of my code:

```
       body: StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection(globals.selectedKat)
                .snapshots(),
            builder:
                (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              } else {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: GridView.count(
                    children: snapshot.data.docs.map((document) {
                      return Center(
                        [...]
                        child: Container(
                          [...]
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Center(
                                    child: Text(
                                  document["titel"],
                                )),
                                Row(
                                  children: [
                                    IconButton(
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          setState(() {
                                            counter++;
                                          });
                                        },
                                        icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline)),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      child: Text(
                                        counter.toString(),
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    IconButton(
                                        iconSize: 40,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          setState(() {
                                            counter--;
                                          });
                                        },
                                        icon: Icon(Icons.remove_circle_outline))
                                  ],
                                )
                              ],
                            )),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                );
              }
            }),
```

And here a Screen of my sim:

[image: screen]

If anything is not clear I'll answer in a few minutes.
Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: Can you post the code for the full screen?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/QdaPwtBk there we go